# RabbitMQ as PaaS (CloudAMPQ) v/s RabbitMQ on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, azure-aks, high-availability, paas

What could be the pros and cons of leveraging RabbitMQ as a PaaS service via CloudAMPQ or as Pods on AKS.

This is taking into consideration HA, DR scenario.

What factors (eg. Retention) can help make the decision?

Comment: any update on this ? feel free to update the status of question if below answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

**RabbitMQ as PaaS (CloudAMPQ)**

- First, benefit without any doubt no responsibility on your shoulder
  if using PaaS.
- Pluggable solution nothing to worry about more

**RabbitMQ on Kubernetes**

- Personal experience we have been running it for a long, your monitoring should be stable, 24*7 support team or rotation-based team if anything goes wrong.
- Understanding required of components how HA works
- Although it's stable however depends on your application and size
- Cost calculation that could affect Business at one stage, so do calculate nodes capacity and a minimum of PODs planning

You can check out this helm chart using this you will be able to deploy the HA rabbitMQ on k8s: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/rabbitmq

i am not sure which version of RabbitMQ your app required, Ordering option required or not do checkout this basic thing also first with Dev.

Accordingly, you can also choose there could be chances on managed services some of version or feature like ordering won't be available.

Comment: So, you have not leveraged the RabbitMQ operator for setting up the cluster on AKS? Instead, you have used Helm Charts to set up the RabbitMQ applications independently on each node as StatefulSets via YAML? Any specific reason for not choosing the operators plugin?

Comment: i am not sure but probably at that time cluster operator was not there maybe rabbitmq launched it around 2020, support started 1.16 K8s version while we were on 1.14, 2018-2019. however, there could be other operators but choose to go with a configuration that i can manage and understand, no doubt operator is a good option always.